# Use of DLL's Class's method

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to include a use DLL's methods using C++.

I've tried to include the DLL using this code:

```
HMODULE DLL = LoadLibrary(_T("name.dll"));

        if (DLL)
        {
            std::cout << "DLL loaded!" << std::endl;


            if (_pdisconnect)
            {
                std::cout << "Successful link to function in DLL!" << std::endl;
            }

            else
            {
                std::cout << "Unable to link to function in DLL!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "DLL failed to load!" << std::endl;
        }
    FreeLibrary(DLL);
```

That DLL that I'm trying to include has two classes `PCls` and `TPCls`. The `PCls` has a method which I'm trying to include is `getOP(LONG a)`. How to use that method, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can't export the class itself you have no instance where to use those functions (assuming nonstatic ones).

Comment: @Marco, do you mean that I need to export for each class one DLL ?

Comment: No, I mean that a non-static member function, to be usable, requires an object of the class it belongs to. If you can't import that object you can't use that function

Comment: @Marco, but, the functions are public. That would be easily exported, isn't it?

Comment: If you have control over the class you're trying to export I suggest to read this first: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't import classes from a DLL, only functions. However, you could have factory functions in the DLL which creates the instances and return a pointer (or you pass in a reference to the factory function that it initializes).

To get a pointer to a function you use [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However note that you must pass it the [*mangled* name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) of the function.

Comment: It's worth noting that trying to `GetProcAddress` a mangled function name is [not necessarily a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314750/find-name-mangled-function-in-dynamically-loaded-dll).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Would you please complete the code for a better understand?