# C++ Need to send std::string over a LAN network

Tags: c++

I need to be able to send an std::string over a LAN network. In my case I have a mac, and a PC that I would like to be able to make communicate. I have taken a look around the web, but haven't had much lucky in terms of solution for my case. Any ideas how I could set up a network through c++ so these computers can share text?

Comment: You should give this a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797418/how-do-i-safely-pass-objects-especially-stl-objects-to-and-from-a-dll

Comment: Have you looked at the Socket API?  What have you tried already?  Do you have a more specific programming question?

Comment: Is it a local area LAN network? Or another kind of LAN network?

Comment: @JAL: C++ doesn't have a Socket API.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit, It is a local area network. Just all of the computers that are connected to my router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost asio library provides a robust framework for doing network communication through sockets. Examples using C++11 can be found here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html

The chat client/ server examples may be of particular interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I haven't tried any of the examples yet, but it should give me a start.