# Segmentation fault in MPI_Send for derived data types

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mpi, openmpi

In the code below, if `MPI_Get_address(&member, &offset[0]);` is replaced with `offset[0] = 0;` the code works as expected otherwise it gives the output below. To my knowledge, for the usage of `MPI_BOTTOM` absolute memory addresses are needed and this is why `MPI_Get_address()` is used. While struct `Member` has no problem with `MPI_Get_address()`, struct `Family` did not work with it. What is the problem?

**Command:**

```
mpirun -n 2 ./out
```

**Output:**

```
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code:  (128)
Failing at address: (nil)
mpirun noticed that process rank 0...
```

**Code:**

```
#include <mpi.h>

struct Member
{
    double height;
    MPI_Datatype mpi_dtype;
    Member() { make_layout(); }
    void make_layout()
    {
        int nblock = 1;
        int block_count[nblock] = {1};
        MPI_Aint offset[nblock];
        MPI_Get_address(&height, &offset[0]);
        MPI_Datatype block_type[nblock] = {MPI_DOUBLE};
        MPI_Type_create_struct(nblock, block_count, offset, block_type, &mpi_dtype);
        MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_dtype);
    }
};

struct Family
{
    Member member;
    MPI_Datatype mpi_dtype;
    Family() { make_layout(); }
    void make_layout()
    {
        int nblock = 1;
        int block_count[nblock] = {1};
        MPI_Aint offset[nblock]; 
        MPI_Get_address(&member, &offset[0]);
        //offset[0] = 0; <-- HERE!!!!!!!
        MPI_Datatype block_type[nblock] = {member.mpi_dtype};
        MPI_Type_create_struct(nblock, block_count, offset, block_type, &mpi_dtype);
        MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_dtype);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int rank;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        Family f;
        MPI_Send(MPI_BOTTOM, 1, f.mpi_dtype, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (rank == 1)
    {
        Family f;
        MPI_Recv(MPI_BOTTOM, 1, f.mpi_dtype, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is not C, and your code is *definitely* not C.

Comment: Since you're well and truly into C++ anyway, have you considered using the C++ interface `MPI::Get_address(void*)` instead?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Aren't c++ bindings depreciated? ([link](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/the-mpi-c-bindings-what-happened-and-why)).

Comment: The C++ bindings are deprecated, yes, but if you're using MPI 2 then they're still there, and can be used.  Whether that's a good idea depends on the nature of your project.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the C++ bindings were **deleted** and are no longer part of the standard as they bring no real advantage over the C bindings. They must simply not be used in newly developed code.

Answer (score 0):

`member.mpi_dtype` already carries the absolute address of `Member::height` as offset in its typemap. When in `Family::make_layout()` you specify `offset[0]` equal to the address of `member`, both offsets sum up, which results in a very wrong offset. For that very reason MPI datatypes with absolute addresses should not be used in constructing other datatypes.

There is absolutely no reason to use `MPI_BOTTOM` in that case - your structures have no dynamically allocated fields and thus MPI datatypes with relative offsets should suffice.

Comment: Actually in my code I have STL objects nearly in every struct. This is why I use absolute addresses. I followed your advise [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069267/segmentation-fault-when-sending-struct-having-stdvector-member).

Comment: Perhaps I haven't make it clear there that such datatypes should not be composed further into other derived datatypes.

Comment: In send/receive operations I would like to group data types consisting of dynamically allocated fields for speed up. I would like to make another data type to group these dynamic data types. Is this impossible since I am making a data type from other data types consisting of dynamic objects?