# Loading dynamcally a DLL inside another DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-dll-import

I'm trying to convert the functionality of our old code to a DLL.

One of the function wants to export from our old code use a dynamically linked DLL (that I'm gonna call `other`)

```
std::wstring otherDLL = L"C:\\PATH\\TO\\OTHER\\DLL"
if (!(libOther = LoadLibraryW(otherDLL.c_str()))){
     return;
}
```

In our old code, this portion of code works just fine.

So I added in my new DLL the following code:

```
extern "C++" std::wstring test_load(void){
    std::wstring otherDLL = L"C:\\PATH\\TO\\OTHER\\DLL"
    if (!(libOther = LoadLibraryW(otherDLL.c_str()))){
         return L"Not Loaded";
    }
    return L"Loaded";
}
```

(this function is not launched during DLLMain). If I try to launch test_load from my DLL in another exe

```
#include "MyNewDLL.h"
int main()
{
    std::wcout << test_load();
}
```

I get following error

> Unhandled exception at 0x7BDE20f3 (ucrtbased.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC00000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

What's strange is that if I try to load the OtherDLL from the main that is not inside MyNewDLL, there is no error and I can use it just fine.

Any Idea where my problem could come from ?

Comment: You made the bad decision of passing / returning an object such as `std::wstring` by value.  Memory is allocated when creating `std::wstring`, so which module is responsible for handling the memory allocation and deallocation?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797418/how-do-i-safely-pass-objects-especially-stl-objects-to-and-from-a-dll)

Comment: Wow, that was not smart indeed. I need still some work as loading still act different when loading from MyNewDLL. However I don't have an exception anymore