# Manually loading dynamic libraries implies virtual functions on classes defined in library

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-linking, loadlibrary, dynamic-library

First I will try to define the question in one sentence, then I will go into details.

Question:
Is there a way to call non virtual functions on class instances created in a DLL, where the implementation is not known at compile and link time, since hidden in a DLL?

Background:
I have a system in place, where I compile a piece of code (a module) into a DLL and load this DLL in my application on-demand when GetModule(Name) is called.

On windows, loading is done with LoadLibrary

```
void* DynamicLibraryLoaderWin::LoadDynamicLibrary(const std::wstring& file_path)
{

    auto* library_handle = LoadLibraryW(file_path.c_str());

    if (!library_handle)
    {
        const auto error = GetLastError();
        assert(false);
    }

    return library_handle;
}
```

After I get the handle, I can create a module instance by calling an exported C function in the DLL that will return me an instance of a my desired module class.

Example Module:

```
class ModuleExample : public IModule
{
public:

   virtual std::string* GetString() const;
};
```

Now, if I want to call GetString() on ModuleExample, I have to make the function virtual. If I don't do that, I will end up with a linker error since there is code somewhere in my application that executes GetString() and the linker cannot find the implementation -> since hidden in a DLL that is not yet present. If I make the function virtual, the linker does not complain since everything goes over the V-table, which is known to the compiler and linker.

Now we can argue that making all functions virtual is the solution, but there is a small overhead for virtual functions that is not trivial for performance critical code. Therefore, I'm searching for a solution to not make all functions virtual.

Another small negative effect is that I cannot make ModuleExample final, since it tries devirtualisation on virtual functions, and the linker complains again.

Maybe interesting:
I'm using CMake to setup my modules and applications, and all modules are defined as libraries with the property INTERFACE, and also linked with INTERFACE. I heard something about MODULE, but did not give it a try yet.

Comment: I am afraid, there is no solution to this. If you are calling a (member) function, linker needs to see the definition of it. Calling through pointer will work - so vtbl solution works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I safely pass objects, especially STL objects, to and from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797418/how-do-i-safely-pass-objects-especially-stl-objects-to-and-from-a-dll)

Comment: @Woodford thx were interesting post. But it does not answer my question unfortunately, since I am in full control of the compiler, c++ version and therefore ABI and all dependent SDKs and libs. But by reading through all the answers, it triggered an idea of using import libraries that can be created when building a DLL.